# How do I add a class to inner HTML of a div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, innerhtml, addclass

I'm trying to work around a seemingly impossible customization for Wordpress. Here is what `<?php the_category();?>` prints out:

```
<ul class="post-categories" >
 <li>
  <a rel="category-tag" title="..." href="...">Category One</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  etc.
 </li>
</ul>
```

I need to add / insert a class into all the `<a>`'s, to make it look like this:

```
<ul class="post-categories" >
 <li>
  <a class="btn" rel="category-tag" title="..." href="...">Category One</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  etc.
 </li>
</ul>
```

So far, I've only found ways to assign additional classes to elements with an existing ID or class.
Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Comment: It doesn't seem at all impossible.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well - I meant impossible without using js... They make it very difficult to alter certain templates.

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery:

```
$(".post-categories a").addClass("btn");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was just about to answer my own question after crashing the W3 tutorial. I can't believe I hadn't come across a longer string like this in my google search. So freakin' simple. Sorry for the boneheadedness...

Answer (score 3):

Since the title says **Using JavaScript**

Try this for a JavaScript solution:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    if (links[i].parentNode.className == "post-categories")
    {
        links[i].className = "btn";
    }
}
```

Or if you're down with the kids and you can use jQuery, you can do:

```
$(".post-categories > a").addClass("btn");
```

Comment: And it will add `.btn` to all the links.

Comment: He already stated that he is using jquery or at least used the jquery tag, so you do not need to front the jquery users! ^^

Comment: @Kevkong I went with the question title, but gave OP the choice of both :P

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
$(function() {
$(".post-categories a").addClass("btn");
})
```